# terraform unable to pass a dynamic list of database ids (list of strings) to sql failover databases parameter

Tags: azure-sql-database, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

```
json variable collection:
"collection1"
{
   "recordset1": 
     {
       "database_id": [
         "/subscriptions/----/HemaSqlDB", 
         "/subscriptions/----/HemaSqlDB2",                    
         "/subscriptions/----/HemaSqlDB3"
       ] 
     } 
 } 

resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "sql_failover" { 
  databases = [var.database_id[0],var.database_id[1],var.database_id[2]]
}
```

how to achieve this dynamically ? i cannot use count_index because failover group is already existing and ì'm trying to add more databases to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the count, you just need to set the databases with the list variable like this:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "sql_failover" { 
  ...
  databases = var.database_id
  ...
}
```

Of course, the list must contain the existing databases and the new databases you want to add into the failover group.

Comment: thank you so much. it was a silly mistake from my side. i was putting it inside array [var.database_id] thinking it was a list.